# If it weren't for marriage. Explain

Tags: phrases

Just saw this quote,

"Just think, if it weren't for marriage, men would go through life thinking they had no faults at all! "

Is it fair to assume the meaning of the below is same as that of the above one? 
If not what is the difference?

"Just think, if there wasn't marriage, men would go through life thinking they had no faults at all! "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two phrases have pretty much the same meaning - "If it weren't for x" is meant to reference the situation in which x doesn't exist so it can be used a comparison.

Comment: "If it were not for X" is the conditional, referring to a hypothetical situation in which X doesn't exist.